# Log4j2 Rolling File Appender IfFileName condition not finding / deleting files

Tags: log4j2, rollingfileappender

I have a program where I am trying to change the default rollover strategy of a rolling file appender programmatically, and it works perfectly if I keep the IfFilName path condition out of it , and only use a IfLastModified path condition, so everything seems to be working perfectly, but then when I add in the IfFileName condition it stops deleting files...

So there is something wrong with the way I am creating this condition.

My xml file has this set up as the appender --

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="cc" filePattern="logs/${baseFileName}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-40t] %-5level %-80.80l - %msg%n"/>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
            <Delete basePath="logs/">
                <IfFileName glob="${baseFileName}-*.log.gz" />
                <IfLastModified age="2d" />
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
```

so, as you can see, each log file is being saved in a logs folder in the base directory, which is named after this property set at the top -

```
 <Properties>
    <Property name="baseFileName" value="VrsEditor"/>
</Properties>
```

it is set up like this because different services of the program have different names so the baseFileName is based on which configuration file/ class is doing the logging...

this configuration file works great and does the job, but when I apply my method to change the default roll over strategy it stops working if I include an IfFileName condition

here is how I am setting up that condition -

```
IfFileName fileName = IfFileName.createNameCondition("${baseFileName}-*.log.gz", "${baseFileName}-*.log.gz");
```

The createNameCondition method is like this--

```
 createNameCondition(                          @PluginAttribute(value="glob")
                                               String glob,
                                               @PluginAttribute(value="regex")
                                               String regex)
```

So for this method I need to pass in A String glob value and a String regex value.... and as you can see above I just used the exact same String that was in the original configuration file because all I want this method to change is the IfLastModified condition for how many days the files are kept.

Does anyone know why this IfFileName condition isn't working even though I am passing in the exact same value as the original configuration file where it works?

I am thinking the only thing it could be is the Regex part as the String part should be exactly the same no?

Any ideas on what kind of regex conversion I need to use to turn "${baseFileName}-*.log.gz" into regex? or if there is some other problem why this IfFileName condition won't work programatically but works from the configuration file itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can debug what's happening by setting `<Configuration status="trace">` at the top of your configuration file. This will print internal Log4j2 debug statements to the console. The custom delete action in Log4j2 has fairly detailed logging.

What I suspect is happening is that the `${baseFileName}` part of your glob is interpreted literally. You want this to be a variable that is replaced by some path before the custom delete action fires, but I suspect the pattern is not replaced.

Debugging will tell you what is happening. If I'm right, the workaround is to use a literal value instead. (And you can raise a feature request on the Log4j2 JIRA issue tracker.)